# Up to 11 GB RAM is used by following SQL Statements, how can I optimize RAM usage?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, garbage-collection, ram

Those are the SQL tables I am taking the data from

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS term_index (\n" 
                        + " term_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,\n" 
                        + " term text ,\n"
                        + " multiterm integer \n"
                        + ");";
        execute(sql);

sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doc_term (\n" 
                + " term_id integer ,\n"
                + " wiki_id text ,\n"
                + " section text ,\n"
                + " freq integer ,\n"
                + " tfidf double ,\n"
                + " cvalue double ,\n"
                + " rake double ,\n"
                + " PRIMARY KEY (term_id, wiki_id, section) \n"
                + ");";
        execute(sql);
```

This is the SQL statement to take the termIDs from the tables above

```
    /**
     *
     * @param wikiID
     * @return
     */
    public HashSet<Integer> getWholeDocumentTermIDs(String wikiID) {
        HashSet<Integer> termIDs = new HashSet<Integer>();

        String sql= "SELECT term_id FROM doc_term WHERE wiki_id = ?";

        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1,wikiID);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String sql2= "SELECT term_id, multiterm FROM term_index WHERE term_id = ?";
                PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                //System.out.println(rs.getInt("term_id"));

                int term_id = rs.getInt("term_id");

                if(term_id != 0) {
                    stmt2.setInt(1,term_id);


                    ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
                    int multiterm = rs2.getInt("multiterm");


                    if(multiterm == 0) {

                        termIDs.add(term_id);
                    }
                    rs2.close();
                }

            }

            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "in getWholeDocumentTermIDs");
        }

        return termIDs;
    }
```

The function getWholeDocumentTermIDs(String wikiID) is called 30 k times, meaning for 30 k wikiIDS, so when executing this, steadily more and more RAM is used by my IDE, starting at roughly 1,3 GB to later up to 10 or 11 GB, at which point the process starts to slown heavily. My question is if and how I can reduce/clean up the RAM to fetch all the required data stored in those tables.

Comment: To reduce the RAM, for every call you should perform all the processing and then free the heap (aka memory/RAM). It seems you are not freeing the heap after each call.

Comment: @TheImpaler and how do I free the heap after each call of this function?

Comment: Isn’t the purpose of a `PreparedStatement` to be created once before the loop, to only alter the parameter and re-execute it inside the loop, instead of creating a new, identical statement in each iteration? Further, you have forgotten to close the `stmt`. Generally, I recommend to use the [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), to get simple and clean code that never forgets to close the resources.

Comment: It also seems that there is a `if(rs2.next()) { … }` missing. Further, you are doing in Java what is a database’s job. Just perform a single join statement and read the results.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for pointing out the issues within the sqllite Code and the corresponding method. By using the JOIN Statement you mean to put both tables together and taking all the data from one table, which wouldn`t require a second inner loop and a second SQL statement, am I right?

Comment: Execute a single statement like `SELECT a.multiterm FROM term_index a, term_id b WHERE a.term_id = b.term_id AND b.term_id = ?`. Hope, I got the syntax right. It’s been a long time since I used SQL.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, I implemented it with a single SQL statement by using the JOIN the way you explained. Additionally he RAM usage of the method is lowered significantly after closing and reducing the statements executed in it. Thanks again for the help. My issues seem to be solved for now.